# Using this d3 gauge in django?

Tags: javascript, django, web, d3.js

I have never used javascript nor d3 in django yet, can anyone run me through on how to include this gauge in my html file in django? I have already npm installed d3-simple-gauge, but I am not sure how to actually use it.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/d3-simple-gauge

My current understanding is: I have to put a script tag including the link, although I am not sure why.

My current don't knows: Do I include the **usage** part in the d3-simple-gauge documentation all between a script tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have already included the needed d3 includes (make sure you are using the correct version for this code -- version 5), then you would put the actual code example in-between   tags. Example:

```
<script>
const svg = d3.select('body')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', 400)
  .attr('height', 250);

const simpleGauge = new window.d3SimpleGauge.SimpleGauge({
  el: svg.append('g'),        // The element that hosts the gauge
  height: 200,                // The height of the gauge   
  interval: [0, 200],         // The interval (min and max values) of the gauge (optional)
  sectionsCount: 2,           // The number of sections in the gauge
  width: 400                  // The width of the gauge
});

setTimeout(() => {
  simpleGauge.percent = 0.7;  // The new percent of the needle to set (70%)

  setTimeout(() => {
    simpleGauge.value = 42;  // The new value of the needle to set inside the interval (21%)
  }, 1500);
}, 1500);
</script>
```

Keep in mind that this project requires d3.js v5 which makes use of promises. Promises simplify the structure of asynchronous code, especially in modern browsers that support async and await.

The example code attaches the svg to the body, however you may want to attach it to a div so you can position it correctly on the page.

If you have further questions about usage, feel free to leave a comment.

Comment: Hey Jason, thanks for guiding me, I think your solution works, but I don't think I am loading "d3-simple-gauge" correctly. In the terminal, it says: Not Found: /d3-simple-gauge.js. And in the code, I put: <script type="text/javascript" src="d3-simple-gauge.js"></script>. I put this because in the documentation the author wrote it says: Be sure to include d3-simple-gauge.js file in your project before to start. May I have misinterpreted his message?

Comment: src="d3-simple-gauge.js" means the file is located in the same directory that site is being served from. Have you already done that? You could also use a CDN for the file but I can't locate one with that js file.

The file you need is located here: https://github.com/antoinebeland/d3-simple-gauge/tree/master/src

If you download that file and include it in your root html directory and check console to make sure the file is being loaded, it should work.